# Probability of having at least one element from a class in a subsample

Tags: probability, combinations, sampling, stirling-numbers

Let's say I have a set of 500 fruits and 5 of them are kiwis (1%).

If I randomly take a sample of 50 fruits from the initial 500 set, **what's the probability of having at least 1 kiwi ?**

I suspect I should use the [Stirling numbers of the second kind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_second_kind) and also, because of the "at least", I imagine it'd be easier to calculate the probability of not having kiwis and then calculate the probability of having at least 1 kiwi as:
$$ Answer = 1 - P(no kiwi)$$

I also know that there are $\left( \frac{500}{50} \right)$ possible samples of size 50 but I cannot put all the pieces together :(

Can you help me ? Many thanks in advance for your time !

**P.S.** I expect this probability to be low but while playing with numbers I end up with something unreasonably small (e.g. ~$10^{-50}$). It is hard also to calculate $\frac{500!}{50!}$... How do you do it ? I cannot multiply by hand $ 500*499*...*51 $, can I ? I guess the correct answer doesn't involve numbers with >1000 digits

Comment: It is, indeed, much easier to compute the probability that none of them are kiwi.

Comment: Probability of no kiwi = (No. of ways of choosing 50 fruits from remaining 495)/(No. of ways of choosing 50 fruits from all 500). Can you take it from here?

Comment: You are correct that calculating the complement is far easier. In this case, the number of ways to pick $50$ fruits, none of them being kiwis, is $\binom{495}{50}$, and the total number of ways is obviously $\binom{500}{50}$. It comes out to $\frac{268540614}{455794085}$, which is a little under $59\%$. Then just take the complement.

Comment: Cheap approximation:  if you assumed you were choosing with replacement, the probability of getting no kiwis is $\left( \frac {495}{500}\right)^{50}\approx .605$  which should be decently close.  Always a good idea to look for simplifying assumptions that generate quick approximations.

Comment: Wow ! Thanks for the answers (it was easier than I imagined. I just messed up the calculations). I don't have the reputation to upvote your answers. Tomorrow I will auto-answer me. Thanks again guys !

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to the comments I can answer my own question. It is actually much easier than I expected (I just messed up the calculations).
Forget about the Stirling numbers, as I said it is much easier to calculate the probability of having **at least one kiwi**, $P(kiwi)$, as:
$$
P(kiwi) = 1 - P(no\_kiwi)
$$
where $P(no\_kiwi)$ is the ratio between the number of ways to pick 50 fruits without kiwis, $\binom{495}{50}$, and the total number of ways of randomly pick 50 fruits, $\binom{500}{50}$.

Explicitly:
$$
\require{cancel}
\begin{aligned} 
P(no\_kiwi) &= \frac{\binom{495}{50}}{\binom{500}{50}} \\
&= \frac{495!}{50!(495-50)!}*\frac{50!(500-50)!}{500!} \\
&= \frac{495!}{\bcancel{50!}*445!}*\frac{\bcancel{50!}*450!}{500!} \\
&= \frac{\bcancel{495!}}{\bcancel{445!}}*\frac{450*449*448*447*446*\bcancel{445!}}{500*499*498*497*496*\bcancel{495!}} \\
&= \frac{18045929260800}{30629362512000} \\
&\simeq 0.59
\end{aligned}
$$
The probability we are looking for is therefore:
$$
P(kiwi) = 1 - 0.59 \simeq 0.41 = 41 \%
$$